# Magento2.4: Display custom CMS block header and footer on homepage

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.3

Add a new CMS block on top of the homepage (header) and another one at the bottom of the homepage (footer) using XML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the core files in your theme or module. I'm overriding in my module have a look into this. Maybe it helps you.

> view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   template="Vendor_Module::html/header.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   template="Vendor_Module::html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

after creating file in layouts simply add header and footer file in templates folder

> view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml

and

> view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You can add the static blocks in the homepage header and footer by adding the below code in your theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Where `header_block` is the name of the CMS block of the header and `footer_block` is the name of the footer CMS block.

Furthermore, if you want to add the template files instead of CMS blocks then there is no need to add the block default class in the XML from Magento 2.3. So the xml code will look like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block name="header_block" template="Vendor_Module::html/header.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block name="footer_block" template="Vendor_Module::html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The theme's file path should be:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: will try that too

Comment: can you take a look at this?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358299/magento2-4-how-to-sort-products-by-sizes-m-l-xl